# CodeIgniter extend CI_URI undefined method

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

So I've been in the process of updating someones old CI 1 to CI 3 code.  In process. In particular, the URI class extension is not working. I've read the CI documentation switched to __construct() and moved it to the application/core directory. I've checked SO and all cases are correct, but I still get the following error:

Call to undefined method MY_URI::last()

My code below

```
class MY_URI extends CI_URI {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function last()
    {
        return $this->segment(count($this->segments));
    }
}
```

Thoughts as to why this may be happening with the switch? Checking StackOverflow it said chek your config settings by the config has the correct

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

I'm calling it with:

```
$lastURI = $this->uri->last();
```

Update: I've also tried the

```
 exit('MY_URI.php loaded');
```

trick at the top which seems to work, but it still throws the error when I remark it out and never loads the extension.

Comment: have you tried changing the function name and seeing if you can access it then? otherwise I don't see an issue with the way you are doing things - unless - whats your file name exactly?

Comment: file is MY_URI.php

Comment: Have you tried my first suggestion?

Comment: Yes I've changed it to blahblah and still the same

Comment: I'm not sure if you can extend the uri class as I've never done it before but you should be able to. Could you try maybe extending another one of the core classes or libraries and trying to access a function just to see if your my loader is working?

Comment: I'm wondering if I have to actually create a controller or a helper beyond the application/core.

Comment: I can confirm that your code works (not getting undefined w/ error reporting on) on my localhost setup running CI 3.8. I have a file in `application/core/MY_URI.php` that contains the same code as above and can access it in a controller as you suggest. I'm not sure why it doesn't work in your system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170061/discussion-between-kevrone-and-alex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your `MY_URI.php` file inside the `application/core/MY_URI.php` & update the function like following.

```
public function last(){      
    return $this->segment($this->total_segments());
}
```

call it like below

```
$last = $this->uri->last();
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain how this differs than what the user is currently doing. He too saves the tile in core and has a function called last. The issue isn't necessarily it's contents as he is getting a call to undefined method.

Comment: This is actually what I've done aside adding public. This doesn't really change anything as noted.

Comment: This hasn't contributed at all. I've removed all of that, I could have put print there but it doesn't change the fact the extension isn't happening. Oddly enough I've tried the exit('MY_Controller.php loaded'); trick and sure enough it exits, but for some reason it's still not extending the class

Comment: @Kevrone, check out my answer. i have updated, add that code inside the autoload.php and check it. i hope now i will work

Comment: No luck. I saw that when looking as well.  It also used .'php' now not EXT

Comment: Frigging Typecase Error...URl vs URI thanks for trying

Comment: Yes, it's not my code, someone had used URl (with a lowercase L) instead of with an (I uppercase i)